# Publishing the css and js file changes in server, but it is not effecting in browser still it is reflectiong old file

Tags: iis-6

I had checked through Firebug and inspect element.The file which was in server is not reflecting in browser .I am sure that new file was published.When i changed the file name and published again then it is effecting in the browser. I had also tried cleaning browser cache in our system and Disk cleanup in server.

Comment: So, did you try a hard browser reload (Ctrl-shift-R)?

Comment: Hurry its working when we do ctrl-shift-R